# Nodejs application with okta authentication throwing 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' error and state mismatch errors

Tags: authentication, okta, okta-api

I have a nodejs application.
On trying to log in, I am getting this error.

dev-xxxxx-okta refused to connect. The error in the log is:

Refused to display 'https://dev-206911.okta.com/login/login.htm?fromURI=/oauth2/v1/authorize/redirect?okta_key=AhxDp3Qod0iqq9VKxFNvd6WTRA601e5Sx0FcPl1lS_k' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Tried to fix it but couldn't. I am seeing the IP address of the VM in the browser logs.

My .env file has the IP address and port of the application. Without the subdomain, it works fine. But with domain the URL https://dev-206911.okta.com/login/login.htm?fromURI=/oauth2/v1/authorize/redirect?okta_key=AhxDp3Qod0iqq9VKxFNvd6WTRA601e5Sx0FcPl1lS_k is throwing this error:

Error: state mismatch, could not find a state in the session, this is likely an environment setup issue, loaded session: undefined
at ..../node_modules/openid-client/lib/passport_strategy.js:169:20
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)